# ASUS E200HA cannot recognize the touch panel....15.10

Tags: 15.10

I know there has many solution for elantech touch panel ,however it base on the system know it is a elantech touch panel. this panel cannot be recognized.
no touch panel in the system setting.
and I try xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PDEC3393:00 0B05:8585                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1000:00 0B05:0101                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

two strange devices....
I do not even know how to start to solve this problem....it will be really nice if I can get some hints.

Comment: This must be some new hardware that is not supported by Linux yet. I suggest reporting it to launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug` linux.

Comment: I have aready send those information to ubuntu bug. hope its work  ,thanks

Comment: You can also try `i8042.nopnp` boot parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The touchpanel on my E200HA works fine for me with xubuntu 16.04.1

As far as I can understand the E200HA uses some very new hardware that is only supported by the most recent kernels.